# Extract only the last line matching each of several patterns from a large input file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file like below.
During command execution, the output got printed like this.

```
     100 files
     200 files
     300 files
     400 files
     500 files
     600 files
     700 files
     800 files
     900 files
   73700 files
   73800 files
   73900 files
   74000 files
   74100 files
   74200 files
   74300 files
   74400 files
   74498 text files.
classified 74484 files
Duplicate file check 74484 files (19369 known unique)                                        
Unique:    17800 files                                          
Unique:    17900 files                                          
Unique:    18000 files                                          
Unique:    18100 files                                          
Unique:    18200 files                                          
Unique:    18300 files                                          
Unique:    18400 files                                          
Unique:    18500 files                                          
Unique:    18600 files                                          
Unique:    18700 files                                          
Unique:    18800 files                                          
Unique:    18900 files                                          
Unique:    19000 files                                          
Unique:    19100 files                                          
Unique:    19200 files                                          
Unique:    19300 files                                          
   49208 unique files.                              
Counting:  47000
Counting:  47100
Counting:  47200
Counting:  47300
Counting:  47400
Counting:  47500
Counting:  47600
Counting:  47700
Counting:  47800
Counting:  47900
Counting:  48000
Counting:  48100
Counting:  48200
Counting:  48300
Counting:  48400
Counting:  48500
Counting:  48600
Counting:  48700
Counting:  48800
Counting:  48900
Counting:  49000
Counting:  49100
Counting:  49200
   28105 files ignored.
```

I need only the final lines.

```
74498 text files.
Unique:    19300 files                                          
Counting:  49200
```

I thought to use sed command but it deletes all the lines. But I need to keep the final line.
Can you suggest me any pattern or command to write code for this requirement ?

I tried this pattern where I deleted lines ending with "files" but it is deleting other lines like starting with "classified and ending with "files". But I want to delete only lines with numbers started.

```
sed '/[0-9] files$/d' gg | sed '/^Unique:/d' | sed '/^Counting:/d' | tee gg
```

My desired output:

```
   74400 files
   74498 text files.
classified 74484 files
Duplicate file check 74484 files (19369 known unique)                                                                                 
Unique:    19300 files                                          
   49208 unique files.                              
Counting:  49200
   28105 files ignored.
```

Comment: It's much faster to just _extract_ the last line into a new file (and maybe overwrite the original file with that new file) than to do anything else, when it's only one line at the end you want to save. Editing large files in-place (for a true meaning of "edit") is surprisingly tricky; there's a reason that programs that do it all the time (like database servers) use files in carefully-designed storage formats built specifically to permit such edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/text files/    {$1=$1; a=$0}
     $1=="Unique:"   {b=$0}
     $1=="Counting:" {c=$0}
     END{print a ORS b ORS c}' file
```

Or as one line:

```
awk '/text files/{$1=$1; a=$0} $1=="Unique:"{b=$0} $1=="Counting:"{c=$0} END{print a ORS b ORS c}' file
```

Output:

```
74498 text files.
Unique:    19300 files                                          
Counting:  49200
```

`$1=$1` forces `awk` to rebuild current row with its default input and output separator. In this case this removes leading spaces.

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, **ORS**, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Thank you Cyrus, But my question is to only remove those lines, I need other lines in the file.

Comment: But your comment is helpful for other requirement of mine.

Comment: And my solution for this particular problem. 
sed '/^[ \t]*[0-9]* files$/d;/^Unique:/d;/^Counting:/d' gg | tee -a output.txt

Comment: That surprises me. You wrote in in your question *I need only the final lines.*

Comment: In your awk syntax, is there any way to fetch the remianing lines not matching the pattern?Like else part

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: sorry for that, I added desired output now.

Comment: I suggest to start a new question with your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file with result is `result_file`:

```
grep "text files" result_file; grep "Unique:" result_file | tail -1; grep "Counting:" result_file | tail -1;
```

Comment: Please split code onto multiple lines when doing so helps reading comprehension.

Comment: It is useful to wait with the answer until the questioner has shown what he has done to answer the question himself.